# Visited JS links in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I'm having a bit of a trouble with Chrome a:visited links colors when reference is in JS:

```
<a href='javascript:openPage("p1", "p2");'>Link to a page with p1 and p2</a>
```

JS behind the scene is something like:

```
this.openPage = function (p1, p2) {
    var url = "MyPage.aspx";
    url += "?Parameter1=" + p1;
    url += "&Parameter2=" + p2;
    window.open(url);
}
```

Other browsers I'd tested with (IE, Firefox, Edge), change the color of the link once it was clicked, even without explicitly writing CSS for it. But Chrome stays still and holds it's positions.

I know about the security issues and that a:visited functionality is very limited, but I don't look for anything fancy, just changing color of the text, something you'd expect to happen but doesn't. Adding CSS won't help

```
a
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited 
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #551A8B;
}
```

Direct page links work fine.

I could work around with adding

```
onclick="this.style.color='#551A8B';"
```

but that would be quite a challenge to change all the links in the app.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I am not 100% sure but chrome may block javascript in the href. That is really not great practice either way. You could use `onclick='openPage("p1", "p2")'`. It would be even better to get the element and assign the click programatically (`yourLink.onclick = function () {...}`)

Comment: @Toni Yeah, that was the initial plan, but the project is huge, so I've decided to do some research on it first to see whether there are a simple way to do that, after all all the other browsers have such behavior by default, why is chrome has to be special...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted your links to show clicked when they were clicked and avoid any issues you may run into because of javascript in the href you could try something like this

```js
function doLink() {
  var p1 = this.getAttribute("data-p1");
  var p2 = this.getAttribute("data-p2");
  
  var url = "MyPage.aspx";
  url += "?Parameter1=" + p1;
  url += "&Parameter2=" + p2;
  alert(url)
}

var links = document.getElementsByClassName("color-change-links");

var link;
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i += 1) {
  link = links[i];
  
  var p1 = link.getAttribute("data-p1");
  var p2 = link.getAttribute("data-p2");
  
  link.href = "#" + p1 + p2;
  link.onclick = doLink;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="color-change-links" data-p1="link11" data-p2="link12">Link to a page with p1 and p2</a><br />
<a href="#" class="color-change-links" data-p1="link21" data-p2="link22">Link to a page with p1 and p2</a><br />
<a href="#" class="color-change-links" data-p1="link31" data-p2="link32">Link to a page with p1 and p2</a><br />
<a href="#" class="color-change-links" data-p1="link41" data-p2="link42">Link to a page with p1 and p2</a>
```

Comment: ye, that would work, but will require quite a work in my case to change all the links we have, I was looking for more a CSS like kind of approach

Answer (score 0):

I agree with toni's comment.
You should use onclick to trigger your function. 
also add a invalid href on your link to make it unvisited to begin with. Upon clicking, it will become visited.

```
<a href='#' onclick="openPage('param1', 'param2')">Link to a page with p1 and p2</a>
```

[see it in code pen.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrBGpv?editors=1111)

Comment: Would require unique href attributes, more like in Tony's answer